# CCMotionStrike doesnt work on device, but does in simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

So i have the latest CCMotionStrike (which uses ccVertexesLineToPolygon). It works as expected in the simulator, but on the device it only draws one segment at a time (i have to release the touch and redraw, it'll then draw only one segment again)

```
//init method:
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
// create the streak object and add it to the scene
streak = [CCMotionStreak streakWithFade:2 minSeg:5 width:5 color:ccc3(255, 0, 0) image:@"streak.png"];
[self addChild:streak];
streak.position = ccp(s.width/2, s.height/2);

-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];   
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];
    [streak setPosition:touchLocation];
    isDrawing = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CCMotionStreak is only intended for one streak...

EDIT:

Put `isDrawing = true;` in `ccTouchesBegan` and in `ccTouchesEnded` put `isDrawing = false;`

Then, remove it from `ccTouchesMoved`

I doubt this has anything to do with it at all but, I always put `streak.position = ccp(s.width/2, s.height/2);` before `[self addChild:streak];`

Comment: I am using only one streak,but a streak is build out of segments (of which only one is drawing on device)...

Comment: I updated my answer, try that. If that doesn't work, I'm not sure what it is because your code looks fine.

Comment: nvm it had something to do with the png i used as segment :S i tried the original from the sample code and that one worked for whatever reason.